# jQuery when using renderWith method error regarding accessing an element id from a jQuery click event

Tags: jquery

I have a problem regarding accessing an element id from a jQuery click event when the actual element is part of template rendered with the method renderWith(). I cannot figure out whats wrong and could surely need some wise input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your element is *rendered* (AKA: created dynamically) try like:

```
$(document).on('click', "#yourElementId", function(){
   alert( this.id ); // Test
});
```

<sub>if that's the case the question is a *dupe* of [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) (Pending Close)</sub>